# Использование DLL C++ с общей секцией в delphi

Tags: c++, delphi, кодировка, dll

Есть dll, написанная на C++. В dll есть функции, которые помещают строку в переменную, которая находится в общей секции данных. То есть такая переменная должна быть доступна из разных приложений, загрузивших данную библиотеку. Данные в переменные записываются с помощью функции SharedStrVarSet, читаются - SharedStrVarGet.

Вот код этой dll (C++)

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#define MT4_EXPFUNC __declspec(dllexport)

using namespace std;
#pragma data_seg(".shared") //Объявляем общую секцию
#pragma comment(linker,"/SECTION:.shared,RWS")
#pragma data_seg()
__declspec(allocate(".shared")) string SharedStrVar1, SharedStrVar2, SharedStrVar3; // объявляем переменные в общей секции данных. Они будут доступны из разных процессов, загрузивших эту dll. Данные в переменные записываются с помощью функции SharedStrVarSet, читаются - SharedStrVarGet

MT4_EXPFUNC void __stdcall SharedStrVarSet(char *InTxt, int i)
{
    string InStr;
    InStr = InTxt;

    switch(i)
    {
    case 0:
        SharedStrVar1 = InStr;
        break;
    case 1:
        SharedStrVar2 = InStr;
        break;
    case 2:
        SharedStrVar3 = InStr;
        break;
    }
}

MT4_EXPFUNC char* __stdcall SharedStrVarGet(int i)
{
    std::string str1(SharedStrVar1);
    std::string str2(SharedStrVar2);
    std::string str3(SharedStrVar3);
    char* s1 = new char[str1.length()+1]();
    char* s2 = new char[str2.length()+1]();
    char* s3 = new char[str3.length()+1]();
    strcpy(s1, str1.c_str());
    strcpy(s2, str2.c_str());
    strcpy(s3, str3.c_str());

    char* out;
    switch(i)
    {
    case 0:
        out = s1;
        break;
    case 1:
        out = s2;
        break;
    case 2:
        out = s3;
        break;
    }
    return (out);
}
```

Код программы на Delphi:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    edt1: TEdit;
    btn1: TButton;
    edt2: TEdit;
    btn2: TButton;
    procedure btn1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure btn2Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

procedure SharedStrVarSet(InTxt:PChar; i:integer); stdcall; external 'HiAsmMQL.dll';
function SharedStrVarGet(i:integer):PChar; stdcall; external 'HiAsmMQL.dll';

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

var
  i:integer;
  txt:string;

procedure TForm1.btn1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  i:=0;
  txt:=edt1.Text;
  SharedStrVarSet(PChar(txt), i);

end;

procedure TForm1.btn2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  edt2.Text:=SharedStrVarGet(0);
end;

end.
```

Теперь о том как это должно работать. В архиве находится сама dll, исходники delphi7, скомпилированная программа: http://au01.ru/CallFuncDll.rar

1. Запускаем Project1.exe
2. Запускаем Project1.exe ещё раз (чтобы получилось 2 копии запущенной программы)
3. В одной копии программы нажимаем кнопку btn1 (отправляет данные из поля edt1 в общую переменную SharedStrVar1, которая находится в dll)
4. Во второй копии нажимаем кноку btn2 (получает данные из общей переменной)

В результате всё Ок. Данные из общей переменной получены.

Далее

1. Вписываем в поле edt1 длинную строку. 40 Символов будет достаточно. и нажимаем btn1
2. Во второй копии нажимаем кноку btn2.

В результате, либо получаем кракозябры, либо программа вылетает.

**В секцию uses в самом начале добавлял ShareMem, результат не изменился.
В приложениях, написанных на C++ dll работает как надо.**

Помогите разобраться в чём причина. Архив с исходниками и dll http://au01.ru/CallFuncDll.rar

Answer (score 1):

Дело в том, что общую область памяти попадает память, непосредственно используемая переменной, в вашем случае это string - т.е. в общей области памяти находится указатель на строку, сама строка не обязана находится в общей области памяти.
В качестве shared переменной попробуйте выделить массив символов (char[]) - должно помочь.

Answer (score 0):

Извините, неверно понял нужен доступ из 2 разных программ. Вот по-моему это то, что нужно
[общий доступ к памяти, распределенной DLL](http://www.tdoc.ru/c/delphi-sources/dll/obschij-dostup-k-pamyati-raspredelennoj-dll.html). Правда там есть пара легко исправлямых ошибок. Я попробовал на ХЕ - работает только почему-то до 14 символов, Ну, я думаю, с распределением памяти тоже реально будет разобраться.

Comment: >`procedure SharedStrVarSet(InTxt:PwideChar; i:integer); stdcall; external 'HiAsmMQL.dll';
function SharedStrVarGet(i:integer):PwideChar; stdcall; external 'HiAsmMQL.dll';`

Нет, так вообще не работает...